# Change in color not getting applied unless I move/scale/modify the object

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs

I am trying to change the color/font of a text using fabric js. The color of the text selected is only getting changed after I play with the object (change dimension of target object). What should I do to make the change reflect immediately ?

Here is my HTML:

```
<md-button colorpicker="rgb"
           class="md-icon-button"
           type="button"
           colorpicker-position="bottom"
           colorpicker-close-on-select
           ng-model="myCtrl.color"
           colorpicker-closed="myCtrl.changeColor()"
           ng-change="myCtrl.changeColor()"> Change Color
</md-button>
```

This pops up a color picker on which anyone can pick a color. This color change is reflected through ng-model and on change I am calling ng-change which invokes my simple function in my controller:

```
model.changeColor = function () {
        model.canvas._activeObject.fill = model.color;
        model.canvas.renderAll();
    };
```

However the color is not changing without making any change to the target object dimension. This is the rest of the controller:

```
var createCanvas = function (width, height) {

model.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("portfolioCanvas"));
        model.canvas.setWidth(width);
        model.canvas.setHeight(height);
        model.canvas.calcOffset();



        var text = new fabric.Text('NAME',
            {left: 200, top: 40, rx: 40, ry: 20, angle: 0, fontSize: 10, 
             fontWeight: 'bold'});


        model.canvas.add(text);
        model.canvas.on({
            'object:moving': onChangeFn,
            'object:scaling': onChangeFn,
            'object:rotating': onChangeFn,
            'object:drag': onChangeFn,
            'touch:drag': onChangeFn,
            'object:modified': onChangeFn
        });
    };


    var onChangeFn = function (options) {
        options.target.setCoords();
        model.canvas.forEachObject(function (obj) {
            if (obj === options.target) return;
            obj.setOpacity(options.target.intersectsWithObject(obj) ? 0.5 :1);
        });
    };
```

I also tried to apply the changes like this but it didnt work as well.

```
    $scope.$$postDigest(function () {
            model.canvas._activeObject.fill = model.color;
            $scope.$digest();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using a version from 1.7.x up.

Please use `canvas.getActiveObject().set('fill', color)` This will automatically invalidate the cache and at next redraw you will get color change.

This is the correct way to do it.

Other way equally correct:

```
var active = canvas.getActiveObject();
active.fill = color;
active.dirty = true;
```

Or enable the statefull cache ( expensive ):

```
canvas.statefullCache = true;
canvas.getActiveObject().fill = color;
```

Or disable the cache completely (not suggested):

```
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
```

Comment: Yes, I figured out the setFill way myself. But thanks for the alternate ways. Will try that out .

Comment: avoid named setters/getters  setFill  vs set('fill", value)  probably going to remove them one day. soon.